In Thunderbird how to copy an IMAP folder into Local Folders
What are proper ways to copy the entire messages in a folder under an IMAP account to a subdirectory of Local Folders in Thunderbird? (I want to keep the original messages in the original IMAP folder. I just want to have a duplicate in a place disconnected from the IMAP server.)
This folder contains about 20,000 messages.
One way I can think of is to select all messages by Ctrl+A in the message header list and then use Copy to in the right-click menu. Is this a right way? Isn't there a menu like Copy this folder to?

Addendum Fri 06 Dec 2024 01:30:55 AM CST
It looks that there is a function to copy a folder at the API level. Is it exposed to the GUI?
cf.
folders API / function copy
https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/stable/folders.html#copy-sourcefolderid-destinationfolderid
